How to dynamically get the user operation gas values?
I'm developing smart wallet based application using ERC-4337 v0.6 . I'm trying to dynamically get the gas values of a user operation.
Currently I'm using Stackup's bundler for sending user operations .
From Alchemy's docs [ https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-estimateuseroperationgas ] , I read that eth_estimateUserOperationGas estimates the gas values for a UserOperation .
Stackup also has support for eth_estimateUserOperationGas method .
I tried calling eth_estimateUserOperationGas method similar to how it is written in Alchemy's docs .
Why is it not working ?
Below is the code for Hardhat test :
it("dynamic userop",async function() {
      const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("amoy-rpc-url"); 
      const signer = new ethers.Wallet(SmartWalletOwnerPrivateKey,provider);
      const nonceVal = await account.getNonce();
      const feeData = await provider.getFeeData();// 2 values of EIP1559
      const maxFeePerGasInWei = ethers.formatUnits(feeData.maxFeePerGas, 'wei');
      const maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei = ethers.formatUnits(feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas,"wei");
      const sender = SmartWalletAddr; // smart account address
      const nonce = String(nonceVal); // smart wallet nonce
      const maxFeePerGas = maxFeePerGasInWei; // from provider.getFeeData()
      const maxPriorityFeePerGas = maxPriorityFeePerGasInWei; // from provider.getFeeData()
      const amount = '30000000000000000'; // amount to send to RECEIVER_ADDR

      const tx = await account["execute"].populateTransaction(RECEIVER_ADDR,amount,"0x");
      let calldata = tx.data;
      console.log("calldata :",calldata);

      const result = await axios.post(
        "stackup-node-url",
        {
          jsonrpc: "2.0",
          id: 1,
          method: "eth_estimateUserOperationGas",
          params: [
            {
              sender: SmartWalletAddr, // smart wallet address
              nonce: nonce, // smart wallet nonce
              initCode: '0x', // smart wallet is already deployed , therefore 0x
              callData: calldata, // encoded calldata of SimpleAccount's execute method 
              callGasLimit: "500000", // hardcoded 
              verificationGasLimit: "500000", // hardcoded  
              preVerificationGas: "500000", // hardcoded
              maxFeePerGas: maxFeePerGas, // from provider.getFeeData()
              maxPriorityFeePerGas: maxPriorityFeePerGas, // from provider.getFeeData()
              paymasterAndData: "0x", // no paymaster , therefore 0x
              signature: "0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000007aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1c" // dummy signature
            },
            EntryPointAddr
          ],
        },
        {
          headers: {
            accept: "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("result :",result);

      const retObj = result.data.result; // this object contains callGasLimit , verificationGasLimit , preVerificationGas

    });

I get the error :
result object : {
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
    date: 'Mon, 15 Jul 2024 05:29:14 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'content-length': '91',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'x-ratelimit-limit': '5',
    'x-ratelimit-remaining': '4'
  },
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.2',
      'Content-Length': '809',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.stackup.sh/v1/node/0a7b04765741d678a0c0ab9657a3ed6e1497a8fa582e0a4f48f8633e3722d604',
    data: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"eth_estimateUserOperationGas","params":[{"sender":"0xb9ee6DD790037808cf22ab17880Bb11b7B94ec99","nonce":"6","initCode":"0x","callData":"0xb61d27f6000000000000000000000000cf3d0e213f632e1a3a8fa7fd7a3d131d77b4c231000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006a94d74f43000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","callGasLimit":"500000","verificationGasLimit":"500000","preVerificationGas":"500000","maxFeePerGas":"327535714305","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"327535714275","paymasterAndData":"0x","signature":"0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000007aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1c"},"0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789"]}'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: '809',
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.stackup.sh',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.stackup.sh',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: null,
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: null,
      autoSelectFamilyAttemptedAddresses: [Array],
      handle: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(alpncallback)]: null,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 5758,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 5686,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 5684
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST /v1/node/0a7b04765741d678a0c0ab9657a3ed6e1497a8fa582e0a4f48f8633e3722d604 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.7.2\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 809\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: api.stackup.sh\r\n' +
      'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 2,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/v1/node/0a7b04765741d678a0c0ab9657a3ed6e1497a8fa582e0a4f48f8633e3722d604',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: null,
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 200,
      statusMessage: 'OK',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.stackup.sh/v1/node/0a7b04765741d678a0c0ab9657a3ed6e1497a8fa582e0a4f48f8633e3722d604',      
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 12,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.stackup.sh',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 809,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.stackup.sh/v1/node/0a7b04765741d678a0c0ab9657a3ed6e1497a8fa582e0a4f48f8633e3722d604',      
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
    [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  data: {
    error: { code: -32521, data: null, message: 'execution reverted' },
    id: 1,
    jsonrpc: '2.0'
  }
}


You got an error -32521. According to the docs it just means the transaction reverts.
https://docs.stackup.sh/docs/-32521-transaction-reverted
